# Dynamically iterate over a matrix block's fields?

Tags: matrix, field

Is there a way to dynamically iterate over a matrix block's fields such that the template doesn't need to know the field handles? This doesn't work:

```
{% for block in entry.myMatrixField %}
    {% for field in block %}
        {# do something with field #}       
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This seems like a simple thing to want to do but I haven't figured out a way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure what you want to do with the fields, but you can access them through fieldLayout.

```
{% for block in entry.myMatrixField %}

    {% for field in block.getFieldLayout().getFields() %}

        {# get properties #}
        {{ field.getField().name }}
        {{ field.getField().handle }}
        {{ field.getField().id }}

        {# get value #}
        {% set handle = field.getField().handle %}
        {{ block[handle] }}

    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

You do kind of need to know what the field types are, in order to know how to display them. `{{ block[handle] }}` will fail for instance if one of the fields is an 'Entry' field, because you can't convert an ElementCriteriaModel to a string. To check the field type you can use `field.getField().type`;

Comment: It's a bit more verbose than I was hoping for, but does what I need. Thank you.

Comment: Get rid of the extra junk and it's just 5 lines! Fyi... see [this answer](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/6964/784) for more complete example.

Comment: I just meant that `block[block.getFieldLayout().getFields()[0].getField().handle]` seems like a long dig to get to the value.